# Using format in two queries in sql

Tags: python, sql, database, format, psycopg2

I have a query I use except.I want to send the table path in format when running the select query.

```
query_2="""select * 
           from {}.{} 
           where date(etl_date) = current_date 
           except select * 
                  from {}_test.{} 
                  where date(etl_date)=current_date"""
       .format(liste[0],liste[1])
```

But naturally I get an error like this.

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

How else can I use the format function here? Thanks...

Comment: The error indicates that the tuple element `liste` is either `null` or contains just one value, and you're trying to access more elements than it contains.

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use simple format for SQL queries; use [sql.Identifier](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for tables, fields and use the [second argument](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) of the execute method to pass variables (if needed).

```py
from psycopg2.sql import Identifier, SQL
connection = psycopg2.connect("...")
cursor = connection.cursor()
suffix = "_test"
identifiers = [Identifier("some_schema"), Identifier("some_table"), Identifier("other_schema%s" % suffix), Identifier("other_table")]
query_2 = SQL("""select * from {}.{} where date(etl_date) = current_date 
              except select * from {}.{} where date(etl_date)=current_date""").format(*identifiers)
print(query_2.as_string(cursor))  # if you want to see the final query
cursor.execute(query_2)
```

Output

```sql
select * from "some_schema"."some_table" where date(etl_date) = current_date
except select * from "other_schema_test"."other_table" where date(etl_date)=current_date
```

This assumes you have multiple schemas in the same database as you can't easily do cross database queries in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank u to this answer